# Is there a way to create a recursive UWP user control?

Tags: xaml, recursion, uwp

I've got a class that has an ObservableCollection of itself embedded within the class.

I'm trying to create a user control that also has a reference to itself in order to display the contents of the observable collection.  However, I'm getting a runtime error whenever I'm trying to run the app.

The error is not overly meaningful: 
XAML parsing failed.
E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE [Line: 91 Position: 58] (which is the line that has the recursive call to the user control)

The class looks something like this (it's been made shorter for illustration purposes)

```
    public class BookChapterVm : IBookChapterVm
    {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ChapterText {get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<IBookChapterVm> Chapters { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IBookChapterVm>();
    }
```

The user control looks something like this (again, unnecessary parts are removed)

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Cgs.Ux.UserControls.HelpTextEditor.BookChapterEditorCtrl">
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.Chapters, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="help:BookChapterVm">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <local:BookChapterEditorCtrl Vm="{Binding}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

I've also tried to set up a recursive data template, but it basically ended up with the same error.

Comment: You've created infinite recursion there, each recursive child is displaying the exact same content.

Comment: Actually, it is not infinite recursion.  The control is displaying a list of objects within itself.  That list of objects is the same as the parent.  It will only go as deep as the nesting of the objects within it.

Comment: The way you've written it above, it's actually displaying the exact same data in all of it's children - you've giving the child DataTemplate the exact same data to display as it's parent, therefore creating infinite recursion and crashing the XAML engine.

Comment: The data template is displaying the Chapters of the parent object.  When it displays that object, it is then displaying the chapters of that object - and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working exemple :

In your page :

```
<local:RecursiveContainer ViewModel="{Binding}" />
```

The code behind :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = BuildBookChapterVM();
    }

    private BookChapterVM BuildBookChapterVM()
    {
        BookChapterVM vm1 = new BookChapterVM { ChapterText = "1" };
        BookChapterVM vm21 = new BookChapterVM { ChapterText = "21" };
        BookChapterVM vm22 = new BookChapterVM { ChapterText = "22" };
        BookChapterVM vm211 = new BookChapterVM { ChapterText = "211" };
        vm1.Chapters.Add(vm21);
        vm1.Chapters.Add(vm22);
        vm21.Chapters.Add(vm211);
        return vm1;
    }
}

public class BookChapterVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChapterText { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<BookChapterVM> Chapters { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<BookChapterVM>();
}
```

The UserControl XAML :

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WpfApp2.RecursiveContainer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChapterText}" />
        <ItemsControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:RecursiveContainer
                        Margin="10,5,0,5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        ViewModel="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The UC code behind :

```
public partial class RecursiveContainer : UserControl
{
    public RecursiveContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public BookChapterVM ViewModel
    {
        get { return (BookChapterVM)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(RecursiveContainer), typeof(RecursiveContainer));
}
```

See image as proof of concept.
I hope it will help you ;)

[image]

Comment: I'll take a look at this in the morning, but I have to say that it looks very promising.  Thank you very much for taking the time to put this together for me.

Comment: Okay, I would not have ever considered switching out my VM property into a Dependency Property.  That one change made the recursion work perfectly.  Of course, my next question is "WHY?".  Why did changing the VM to a dependency property make the difference?

Comment: The DataContext is inherited from the top level I believe. With a DP, it allows to specify the data you need.

Comment: I follow what you mean, but it still feels like a bit of a "black box" solution - something under the hood makes it work if it's used in this fashion.  In my head I can sort of rationalize why it works … but like I mentioned earlier, I would never have considered changing the VM to a dependency property.